# matlab GA optimization weird behavior

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm a new user of the optimization toolbox and I'm starting with an easy example.
I made a function:

```
function [ output ] = testGA( input )
output = 2*input^2 + 4*input + 3;
end
```

and this is my script that runs the optimization:

```
OptFun = @testGA;
numvars = 1;
[x fval] = ga(OptFun, numvars);
```

And it totally fails to find the minimum:

```
x = -1.002
fval = 1
```

Am I missing something?
Also how do I get info about all the iterations it performed?

Thank you,
Guido

Answer (score 0):

The minimum of the function you defined is -1 and the corresponding function value 1, so I would not say 'totally fail to find the minimum'. For knowing the number of iterations, type of minimization etc you can use the outputs of ga by:

```
 [x,Fval,exitFlag,Output] = ga(OptFun, numvars)
```

I suggest you look at he documentation of the function ga https://fr.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/genetic-algorithm-options.html where it is explained how the algorithm works and how to change the minimization parameters. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was plotting a different function. lol.
However the output function doesn't really give much infos...How do I tell GA to do a specific num of generations? and how big is the generation size? I would like to have control over these settings...

Comment: Lol no pb, again in section 'Modifying the Stopping Criteria' in https://fr.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/genetic-algorithm-options.html you can find how to control the number of iterations which is 100 by default. It can be specified in the options of function ga opts = optimoptions(opts,'MaxGenerations',150,'MaxStallGenerations', 100);. In section 'Specifying Population Options' you can find how to change the population options. Good luck!